I am incorrectly specifying parameters for the command in ffmpeg
[out#0/dash @ 0x55eee3309600] Codec AVOption minrate (minimum bitrate (in bits/s). Most useful in setting up a CBR encode. It is of little use otherwise.) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[out#0/dash @ 0x55eee3309600] Codec AVOption threads (set the number of threads) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[out#0/dash @ 0x55eee3309600] Codec AVOption maxrate (maximum bitrate (in bits/s). Used for VBV together with bufsize.) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (av1 (libdav1d) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> opus (libopus))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x55eee3356500] v1.11.0
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x55eee3356500] Neither bitrate nor constrained quality specified, using default CRF of 32
[dash @ 0x55eee330c440] No bit rate set for stream 0

What's wrong with my command?
Am I indicating the maximum and minimum rates incorrectly?
ffmpeg -i /2160.mp4 -deadline best -speed 1 -movflags +faststart -map_metadata -1 
         -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ar 48000 
         -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -keyint_min 150 -g 240 -tile-columns 4 -frame-parallel 1 
         -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 
         -filter:v:2 scale=-2:360,fps=30 -minrate:v:2 138k -b:v:2 276k -maxrate:v:2 400k    -tile-columns:v:2 1 -threads:v:2 4  
         -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" 
         -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" 
         -dash_segment_type webm 
         -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 10 
         -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" 
         -f dash /test/dash.mpd


You are filtering/setting the min-max rate for the 2nd stream only by using v:2, you probably need to change that to apply for stream 0 (the main video stream, as seen in map 0:v:0) by changing them to v:0.
Full command would be something like:
ffmpeg -i /2160.mp4 -deadline best -speed 1 -movflags +faststart -map_metadata -1 \
       -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ar 48000 \
       -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -keyint_min 150 -g 240 -tile-columns 4 -frame-parallel 1 \
       -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 \
       -filter:v:0 scale=-2:360,fps=30 -minrate:v:0 138k -b:v:0 276k -maxrate:v:0 400k -tile-columns:v:0 1 -threads:v:0 4 \
       -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
       -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
       -dash_segment_type webm \
       -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 10 \
       -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
       -f dash /test/dash.mpd


Thank you, I wanted to ask.
If you specify several threads and write before each one -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0(I don't know if this is right).The question is, is it possible to make it so that there is one audio track, but several video streams. That is, not for each video stream its own audio track (the same one), but only one. In order to reduce the size of the output file (disk space)

Maybe that's how it works at the moment, I'm just not sure about it.

That is, one audio track (audio file) is played on all video streams.

I'm not closely familiar with mapping two video streams, but I'd assume that if you map audio only the first time (with the first video mapping) and in the next mapping you don't map audio, that would result in one audio track for all video streams

Thanks you.....
